# How to format timestamp field with AWK/GAWK

Tags: awk, printf

I am processing a CSV file with GAWK that has a field with a timestamp formatted like this "18-APR-22 11:00:00". I would like to format the date like this in the output of awk "2022-04-18 11:00:00". I was doing this with the "date -d" and getline. As in the following example.

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '
{
  tmp = "date -d \""$1"\" +\"%F %T\""
  tmp | getline var
  close(tmp)
}
{split(FILENAME, arr, ".")}
{print NR, arr[1], tmp, $4, $7, $8, $9}
' 13003.ARR > test.csv
```

While this works it is very slow with large files. Is there a better way to take the timestamp field and change its format?

Comment: This is what you should do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123961/awk-cannot-open-pipe-too-many-open-files you have to modify the months string, lowercase to uppercase, and to print what you want.

Comment: Running `date` every time you want to convert "18-APR-22" to "2022-04-18" is a suboptimal method. Treat it as a simple string manipulation. Split the string on the `-`s. Then, `18`->`18` is easy, as is `22`->`2022`. `APR`->`04` is table lookup away

Comment: To slightly *re-cast* @thanasisp comment: [Read the fine manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html); in this case the `gawk` manual, but as it states, `mawk` has also incorporated the `Time functions`.

Comment: Using time functions is overkill for this problem: the same translation of 22 -> 2022 and APR -> 04 will still be required to call mktime().

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Thanasisp. Your comment was spot on. I am using the following now and it is thousands of times faster. A csv with 240,000 records runs in three seconds.

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '{
  split(FILENAME, fname, ".")
  split($1, date_time, " ")
  split(date_time[1], date, "-")
  print NR, name[1], "20" date[3] "-" sprintf("%02d", (match("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", date[2]) + 2) / 3) "-" date[1] " " date_time[2], $4, $7, $8, $9
}' 13003.ARR > test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date field to be rearranged is the first , you can do as shown: also you can change the date field index on the awk command line as shown here.

```bsh
awk \
  -v dtFldIdx=1 \
  -v century="$(date '+%C')" \
  -v m=";$(LC_ALL=C locale mon)" \
'
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
  for (i=1; match(m,/;/); i += sub(/;/,"",m))
    a[toupper(substr(m,RSTART+1,3))] = i
  f="%s-%s-%s %%s"; g="%02d"
  fmt = sprintf(f,g g,g,g)
}
{split(FILENAME,arr,".")}
{
  # transform the date field
  split($(dtFldIdx),d,/[-[:blank:]]+/)
  day=d[1]
  mon=a[toupper(d[2])]
  yy=d[3]
  hhmmss=d[4]
  var = sprintf(fmt,century,yy,mon,day,hhmmss)

print NR, arr[1], var, $4, $7, $8, $9}
' file.csv
```

---